# Operand data type varchar is invalid for sum operator

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum

I try this query

```
Select 
S.Name,S.No,
SUM(Case when s.Model='Cultus' then total else 0 end) as Cultus,
SUM(Case when s.Model ='vigo' then total else 0 end) as vigo,
SUM(total) total_v ,
 s.MA,MAX(S.Speed) Speed
 from (
Select
 RVU.Name,RVU.No,VV.Model,count(VV.Model) as total, RVU.MA as MA,RVU.Speed 
from 
 VV 
inner join RVU
on VV.MID=RVU.ID 
inner join RU on RVU.RID= RU.RID
    WHERE 
RU.StartDate>= '2016-04-01 00:00:00' and
RU.EndDate<='2016-04-30 23:59:59'   and
RU.Region= 'Paris'
and RVU.No= '651' AND Model <> ''
Group By RVU.Name,RVU.RegNo,VV.Model,RVU.MA,RVU.Speed ) S
GROUP BY
s.RegNo,s.Name,S.MA
```

Ouput

```
Name    No  Cultus  vigo    total_v   MA       Speed
David   651    2    0        2         1048      124
David   651    3    0        3         597      345
David   651    1    0        1         606     101
David   651    3    2        5         992     110
```

when i try this

```
Sum(MA) MA,
```

THIS SHOW ERROR

**Operand data type varchar is invalid for sum operator.**

I want result like this

```
Name    No     Cultus   vigo    total_v   MA    Speed
David   651    9         2       11       1799    345
```

**UPDATE**

when i try this

```
SUM(CASE ISNULL(MA,'') WHEN '' THEN 0 ELSE CAST(MA AS INT) END),
```

and also this

```
sum(cast (MA as int))
```

then output is

```
 Name   No  Cultus  vigo    total_v     MA     Speed
David   651    2    0        2          4192     124
David   651    3    0        3         2388      345
David   651    1    0        1         2424      101
David   651    3    2        5         4960      110
```

**updated 2:**

when i execute only this part this show multiple records with same data

```
 Select
     RVU.Name,RVU.No,VV.Model,count(VV.Model) as total, RVU.MA as MA,RVU.Speed 
    from 
     VV 
    inner join RVU
    on VV.MID=RVU.ID 
    inner join RU on RVU.RID= RU.RID
        WHERE 
    RU.StartDate>= '2016-04-01 00:00:00' and
    RU.EndDate<='2016-04-30 23:59:59'   and
    RU.Region= 'Paris'
    and RVU.No= '651' AND Model <> ''
    Group By RVU.Name,RVU.RegNo,VV.Model,RVU.MA,RVU.Speed
```

looks like value totally change

Comment: Is your MA column is a varchar data type?

Comment: In that case you cannot aggregate the column, Aggregation is performed only for integer columns. I ll tell you how to aggregate string column

Comment: Posted the answer

Comment: Don't store numeric data in varchar columns! The solution is to alter data type to integer, no to do quick cast fixes.

Answer (score 1):

There may be a chance of string value in the column RVU.MA. Try out with the below query to find out such descrepancies.

```
   SELECT *
   FROM RVU
   WHERE ISNUMERIC (RVU.MA)!=1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below syntax to get your answer.

```
select sum(cast(columnname as int)) from TableName
```

Try applying this syntax:

```
select sum(cast(s.MA as int)) from (
Select
  RVU.Name,RVU.No,VV.Model,count(VV.Model) as total, RVU.MA as MA,RVU.Speed 
from 
  VV 
inner join RVU
on VV.MID=RVU.ID 
inner join RU on RVU.RID= RU.RID
WHERE 
RU.StartDate>= '2016-04-01 00:00:00' and
  RU.EndDate<='2016-04-30 23:59:59'   and
RU.Region= 'Paris'
and RVU.No= '651' AND Model <> ''
Group By RVU.Name,RVU.RegNo,VV.Model,RVU.MA,RVU.Speed ) S
```

Check this query, whether you were able to select your record and apply this logic in your query.

Your final query looks like,

```
Select 
S.Name,S.No,
SUM(Case when s.Model='Cultus' then total else 0 end) as Cultus,
SUM(Case when s.Model ='vigo' then total else 0 end) as vigo,
SUM(total) total_v ,
sum(cast(s.MA as int)),MAX(S.Speed) Speed
from (
Select
RVU.Name,RVU.No,VV.Model,count(VV.Model) as total, RVU.MA as MA,RVU.Speed 
from 
VV 
inner join RVU
on VV.MID=RVU.ID 
inner join RU on RVU.RID= RU.RID
WHERE 
RU.StartDate>= '2016-04-01 00:00:00' and
RU.EndDate<='2016-04-30 23:59:59'   and
RU.Region= 'Paris'
and RVU.No= '651' AND Model <> ''
Group By RVU.Name, RVU.RegNo, VV.Model, RVU.MA, RVU.Speed ) S
GROUP BY
s.RegNo, s.Name, S.MA
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that one of your MA column value is type of varchar, please check your data

If your data type varchar then **cast to INT**:

```
SUM(CASE ISNULL(MA,'') WHEN '' THEN 0 ELSE CAST(MA AS INT) END)

DECLARE @tblTest as Table(
    Name VARCHAR(10),
    No INT,
    Cultus  INT,
    vigo INT,
    total_v INt,
    MA VARCHAR(5),
    Speed INT
)

INSERT INTO @tblTest VALUES
('David',651,2,0,2,1048,124)
,('David',651,3,0,3,597,345)
,('David',651,1,0,1,606,101)
,('David',651,3,2,5,992,110)

SELECT
    Name,[No],SUM(Cultus),
    SUM(vigo) AS vigo ,SUM(total_v) AS total_v,
    SUM(CASE ISNULL(MA,'') WHEN '' THEN 0 ELSE CAST(MA AS INT) END) AS MA,
    MAX(Speed) AS Speed
FROM @tblTest
GROUP BY Name,[No]
```

Comment: there is no varchar value  i checked

Comment: What is datatype of your column? it must not be type of string/varchar/nvarchar

Comment: datatype is varchar

Comment: remove S.MA from group by

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123515/discussion-between-sandip-patel-and-user6628729).

Answer (score 0):

```
create table #t
(
id varchar(20))



insert into #t
select '2'
union all
select '3'

select sum(id) from #t--this fails
```

You need to do

```
select sum(cast (id as int))--cast from 2008 onwards
from #t
```

In your case MA column is of type Varchar

Comment: when i try your solution MA values changes. e.g. 103 change to some another value smae for others

Comment: I don't get what you are sayiong,please update question

Comment: @user6628729:You need to group by,please don't continue asking updatd questions